# How to tranform soap call request into json

Tags: json, xml-parsing, transform

I have a case with existing application. the application interaction with server using web sevice. But, nowadays the server  change the request from web service soap into json. any idea how to transform/convert existing request from client (using soap xml) into json without change the code in client? maybe using api gateway or else

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved, by using feature on ESB. Transformation Message.